# Which is the quickest, safe or unsafe, way to read 16, 32, 64 bit integers from a &u8[] in Rust?

Tags: rust

Assume you have a slice and you want to read little and big endian integers from it. Is there a better way than to use unsafe pointers?

Comment: https://crates.io/crates/byteorder/

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [byteorder](https://crates.io/crates/byteorder/) crate. For some usage examples, see the [docs](http://burntsushi.net/rustdoc/byteorder/).

> ```
> use std::io::Cursor;
> use byteorder::{BigEndian, ReadBytesExt};
>
> let mut rdr = Cursor::new(vec![2, 5, 3, 0]);
> // Note that we use type parameters to indicate which kind of byte order
> // we want!
> assert_eq!(517, rdr.read_u16::<BigEndian>().unwrap());
> assert_eq!(768, rdr.read_u16::<BigEndian>().unwrap());
> ```

Comment: Please don't post answers which depend on off-site links for meaningful content.

Comment: I edited your answer to provide a quick quote of the docs, feel free to revert the edit if it does not suit you, but please add an example then.